# navigate between sheets in excel

Tags: vba, excel

Im writing a macro to navigate between sheets of an excel workbook just like Alt+Tab works between windows. (I know, there is Ctrl+PgUp and Ctrl+PgDn commands, but those buttons have bad location on the keyboard.)

The macro:

```
Sub navigate_sheet()

    If ActiveSheet.Index < Sheets.Count Then    
        ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Next.Select    
    Else    
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Select    
    End If

End Sub
```

It works perfectly in the original file, but when i try to use it in other excel i get Run-time error '1004' and Debug highlights the following line:

```
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Next.Select
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Does the error include a message?

Comment: The code should work fine on any active workbook.

Comment: Run-Time error '1004': Select method of Worsheet failed.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub navigate_sheet()

Dim wb As Workbook    
Set wb = ThisWorkbook

If ActiveSheet.Index < wb.Sheets.Count Then
    wb.Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Select
Else
    wb.Sheets(1).Select
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Same result, Run-Time error '1004': Select method of Worsheet failed.